# Does Excel have the feature to create views similar to Database views?

Tags: microsoft-excel

From Wikipedia:

> In database theory, a view is the result set of a stored query on the
>   data, which the database users can query just as they would in a
>   persistent database collection object. This pre-established query
>   command is kept in the database dictionary.

I need a similar feature in Excel, where I can maintain the unfiltered data in separate sheets, while being able to create multiple "view" sheets with dynamically generated subsets of those data, all within the same excel file.

Comment: Have you tried using pivot tables?

Comment: No Pivot tables doesn't work for this. Pivot tables are for data summarization. I am looking for a filtered view without any manipulation of data and re-arranging of column into rows or vice versa.

Comment: I think from my question it is quite clear that I am not sure whether a feature exists or not. If I don't know whether a feature exists or not, what can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Pivot Add-In for this requirement.

You can load a Power Pivot Table from an Excel Table or a range of other data sources.  Then you can pull the data out using Pivot Tables, Pivot Charts or Flattened Pivot Tables.  From any of those objects you can use the Show Details command to view the underlying detailed data.